# click on UIImageView to change ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, segue, uistoryboard

I have a custom image (profile picture) that I want to click and go to a profile view. I am registering the click, and I have the segue set up in storyboard, but when I click, nothing happens. The profile picture is part of a PFTableViewCell(using parse), which is part of a PFQueryTableViewController. I am trying to navigate to another PFQueryTableViewController. Here is how they are connected on storyboard:

[image]

And here is what I'm trying to do in the code to transition:

```
func onProfileTap(send:AnyObject){
    NSLog("Profile Clicked")

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    var vc:WrapperProfileViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ProfileViewController") as! WrapperProfileViewController
    vc.parseUser = parseUser!
    holder?.navigationController!.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    //holder is a PFQueryTableViewController. "self" is PFTableViewCell
}
```

I have done something very similar to this before and it worked. I checked to make sure the segue identifier is correct, but nothing happens other than the NSLog printing to the console.

Comment: Use delegate to pass the control to PFQueryTableViewController and there handle the pushing view controller.

Comment: Is your "Main Feed" embedded in a UINavigationController (can't tell from above). Definitely should be if you are going to do a "pushViewController".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just looking at your code, and knowing nothing else about your situation, I would guess that `holder` is `nil`. That would certainly be a reason by "nothing happens". You can easily test that with another `println` statement.

Comment: Yes this is the case. What is confusing to me is that I have a different ViewCell in a different ViewController, and both are nearly identical, and doing the exact same thing works. I instantiate them the same way, and everything is the same except for content and their locations on the storyboard. The one I'm having trouble with is the "main feed" view that is presented after login, and the one that works is linked by one of the tab bar items. I will continue to investigate their differences.

Comment: Okay, but I believe I've answered the question you asked, namely, why nothing is happening. You did not give enough info to go any further, and my answer covers the info you did give.